# Image is not showing in Laravel project after uploading in cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have uploaded a laravel project in cPanel.

`public` folder of my project is uploaded inside `public_html` of cPanel. Other folders are uploaded in the root folder of cPanel.

Now Those images which are shown are uploaded while I run the project locally and those images are now inside the `public_html/storage/` in cPanel.

When I am uploading another images in my project from cPanel those are uploaded inside the root folder `myProjectName/storage/app/public`

Here is the picture

[image]

Here is the red mark image is not shown and this image I have added after uploading the project in cPanel.

Any body help please?

Comment: Why do you understand this?
Most of us won't because there is so little information you supply. 
Take a look at the source-code and the web inspector, what do they say?

Comment: What is the current path vs. what's the path meant to be?

Comment: @Andy Holmes.......url.com/storage/myFile.jpg....path means image src...

Comment: @Tom Lankhorst...What you won't understand ? Please ask if any query

Comment: @raff I'm aware of what a path is, I'm asking you what is the current path of the image that isn't loading, and what is the path that it should be?

Comment: @AndyHolmes...current image is `url.com/storage/myFile.jpg`...It sould be `url.com/../../admin_panel/storage/app/public/myFile.jpg

Comment: Can you add the code of how you want to retreive / display the image? You lack information in your question.

Comment: @killstreet ... I have updated my post...please check

Comment: I'm sorry but even this information is not enough for proper help. First of: You say you only uploaded the public folder inside public_html? Unless your using virtualhost files, this will not work. Second, there is yet no code of how you retreive your files, and what result they have along with what it should be. Please add this so we can help you properly.

Comment: We're going to need to see some code to help you out properly. Thanks for clarifying the 2 paths but it's not helpful at the minute

Comment: @Andy Holmes... I am very much sorry for not properly clarifying... I can't explain exactly what i want... :(

Comment: I understand what you want, but we need to see the code you're using to retrieve the image

Comment: @Andy Holmes.........will you please look at this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145262/error-missing-storage-symlink-for-voyager-admin-panel-in-cpanel]

Answer (score 1):

if use laravel storage to uploaded run below in terminal

```
php artisan storage:link
```

take care what is directory permission !!!and in sever file uploaded or not.
if uploaded where is uploaded?

Comment: This command will work unless you got no access to shell. There's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

To clearify some stuff, the other answer by @Mahdi Bahari would be correct. 
When files are stored outside your laravel project you must do a

```
php artisan storage:link
```

If however you are unable to get shell access with your host, then you should probably not upload images outside the laravel project. My first recommendation would be using laravel's storage folder. Which is what laravel uses to store folders / images for the project. [Laravel file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem)