# error `Missing storage symlink` for voyager admin panel in cPanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel, voyager

I have uploaded a voyager admin panel in my cPanel. 
It gives error `Missing storage symlink`and images are not shown of new added item.

Suppose I want to add a new user. All information is shown of new user accept user avatar.

In locally error is easily fixed by running the cmd `php artisan storage:link`.

But in live server how to fixed this error ?

I have already change the path of `storage driver` in `config/filesystems.php`. Change the path from `storage_path()` to `public_path()`

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Comment: Any problem with this ques ?

Comment: `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',` Is there storage directory under `public`?

Comment: @Tpojka... No...Image stored in root(home) directory. But image url path is  webroot directory...But how to change image url path to root directory ?

Answer (score 15):

FIXED !!

Delete `public/storage` folder and run the command in cmd

`php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 2):

this works for me !

```
cd public_html
ln -sr ../storage/app/public storage
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a path related problem. I have changed the `App_url` in my `.env` file. Now it's successfully showing the image.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It happened because the file structure or something changed from the original Laravel setup. For me, I switched from using Artisan to vagrant.

I resolved by logging into vagrant and removing the original symlink:

```
rm -rf /home/vagrant/code/public/storage
```

I went ahead and created the new symlink but you should now be able to click the Fix link in Voyager admin to create the new one.

```
ln -s /home/vagrant/code/storage/app/public /home/vagrant/code/public/storage
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the storage path into de filesystems.php file

to:

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('./../../public_html/storage'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by deleting the public/storage link and folder and then create again the folder and then:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

EDIT:

I also had to set this configuration in the filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
           'driver' => 'local',
           'root' =>  public_path('storage'),
           'url' => env('APP_URL').'storage',
           'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by most easy way:

> remove storage folder from public directory, then hit fix button from
> admin area